# Typescript const return empty

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Working:

```
export interface PlayersResponse {
    status: number;
    maxplayers: number;
    online: number;
    players: string[];
}

const getPlayers = async (uuid: string): Promise<PlayersResponse> => {
    const { data } = await http.get(`/api/client/servers/${uuid}/status`);
    return (data.data || []);
};
```

Not working:

```
export interface PlayersResponse {
    status: number;
    maxplayers: number;
    online: number;
    players: string[];
}

const getPlayers = async (uuid: string): Promise<PlayersResponse> => {
    if(uuid === "") return [];
    const { data } = await http.get(`/api/client/servers/${uuid}/status`);
    return (data.data || []);
};
```

Why?
I need return nothing (empty) on getPlayers if uuid is empty. How i can do that? Thanks. I try:
`return;`
`return [];`
But everytime get error

> Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'PlayersResponse': status, maxplayers, online, players

Comment: What is `data.data` supposed to be? An array of players? If so, you should update the return type to be an array. Otherwise, should you really be returning an array if `data.data` is falsey?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just return `[]` because the return type of `getPlayers` is `Promise<PlayersResponse>`.

One way is the following:

```
const getPlayers = async (uuid: string): Promise<PlayersResponse | null> => {
  const { data } = await http.get(`/api/client/servers/${uuid}/status`);
  
  if (data == null) {
    return null;
  }  

  return data.data;
};
```

Comment: Simple `return (data.data || []);` works perfect. Problem in `return [];` only.

Comment: No, its not, you aren't returning a promise of arrays, this is why `return [];` is typed as `never[]`.